# The service "serializer" has a dependency on a non-existent service "fos_rest.serializer.exception_wrapper_normalizer"

Tags: symfony, service, fosrestbundle

I have cloned a Symfony project on my computer and when I launch it I have this error :

```
ServiceNotFoundException in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 58:
The service "serializer" has a dependency on a non-existent service "fos_rest.serializer.exception_wrapper_normalizer".
```

I just find the relation between these two services in FOS/RestBundle :

```
<service id="fos_rest.serializer.exception_wrapper_normalizer" class="FOS\RestBundle\Serializer\ExceptionWrapperNormalizer">
<argument type="service" id="translator" />
<tag name="serializer.normalizer" />
</service>
```

The serializer is activated too in Symfony (in config.yml) :

```
serializer:
enabled: true
```

How I can find more informations ? How I can resolve this problem ?

Comment: Do FOS RestBundle is activated ? `composer install`done ?

Comment: yes RestBundle is activated in the Kernel

Comment: have you got a line in your config.yml referencing fosrestbundle ? Without that the bundle isn't activate

Comment: Should I post an answer ? :)

Comment: I think you should post an answer for future users who might struggle on a similar point

Answer (score 2):

Juste run this command :

```
composer require translator
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your Answer, please edit your Answer to include an explanation of what you think is causing their problem and how your Answer solves their problem.